# Swarms: Do they qualify for Flanking an enemy?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat

My druid wants to start summoning swarms for the rogue to use as a flanking buddy. Would this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, a swarm does not threaten creatures,¹ even those it is covering, and so does not cause flanking.

> Swarms do not threaten creatures in their square, and do not make attacks of opportunity with their swarm attack. However, they distract foes whose squares they occupy, as described below.

> Flanking
>
> When making a melee attack, you get a +2 flanking bonus **if your opponent is threatened** by a character or creature friendly to you on the opponent’s opposite border or opposite corner.

No threatening, no flanking.

That said, note this is due to it being a swarm, not because it is summoned. All swarms cannot flank,¹ and non-swarm summons can (generally; other creatures may also have exceptions like swarms do).

Finally, considering that *summon swarm* does not give the caster fine control over the swarm, it was probably a poor idea anyway. *Summon nature’s ally* is all around far better for flanking, and giving allies a flanking buddy is one of the best uses of summoning.

1. <sub>**Strictly** speaking, the only explicit rules here are that swarms do not threaten their own squares, and do not make attacks of opportunity with their swarm attack. In theory, if you had a swarm that could reach squares beyond its own space, and a way to make a non-swarm melee attack with that reach, there isn’t any rule saying they do not threaten with these things. Since a creature normally threatens squares it can reach with a melee attack, and nothing says the swarm can’t, it would, and thus would be able to take attacks of opportunity and flank. But only if the target isn’t in one of its own squares, since if it is, the blanket ban on not threatening its own squares would apply. There are no printed swarms that do this, certainly nothing you can get with *summon swarm*, and almost every possible way to become a swarm will strip you of your attacks. I say “almost,” however, because it is possible to gain swarm traits—but not the swarm subtype—through lycanthropy, by being a were-rat-swarm (rat swarms are Animals, despite rats being Vermin) or were-murder-of-crows (*Tome of Magic*). Having swarm traits without the swarm subtype is a nearly incoherent mess of the rules, but it does check out, RAW.</sub>